# Lagrange multiplicator/unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, vectors, lagrange-multiplier

let $\vec{v} = (2,1,-2)^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^3$  and $S^2$ the unit sphere
hence
$\mathbb{S} = \{ (x,y,z)^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \} $

Define the shortest distance from $\vec{v}$ to $\mathbb{S}$

The function I set up was
$$F(x,y,z, \lambda) = \sqrt{(2-x)^2+(1-y)^2+(-2-z)^2}+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$

but I fear that this is not the way how  I  can calculate the distance, could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you were instructed to find the distance *using Lagrange multipliers*  you have it set up right. There is a faster way using the vector from the origin to your point $(2,1,-2)$ however.

Comment: Hint: How about minimize the squared distance?

Comment: @coffeemath, thank you, but I think I do not understand the faster way, the distance from $v$ to the origin would be $3$, but how can I use this information?

Comment: @DiegoMath: yes, thank you, I think it would be faster to minimize the squared distance

Comment: galaxy--- So as I asked, are you *required* to solve with Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1):

To finish the shorter way just subtract $1$ (the unit sphere radius) from that distance from $v$ to the origin which was $3$ so shortest distance is $2.$ You may want to draw a picture of the sphere and your point $v$ which is outside it to see what is going on. The shortest distance from a point $p$ outside the unit sphere to the surface of the unit sphere is always one less than the distance from the origin to $p.$

Note that Diego's suggestion would make the Lagrange multiplier method work fairly well. If you get it I suggest putting it in your question.